# Preventing a component from accepting global styles in vue Js 3 or Nuxt js

Tags: css, vuejs3, vue-component, nuxtjs3

I have a component which I want to prevent from accepting global styles. I have tried using scoped on the component but it does not work.

I tried using scoped style, and I was expecting that apart from preventing my component styles to be globally accessible, it will also prevent my component from accessing global variable. But this seems not to be working.

Comment: You can not go against the running/execution flow of nuxt js or vue js project files. main css/scss file from assets folder will always executed at last.

Comment: `scoped` styles only prevent component styles from leaking out, it does not prevent global or unscoped parent/root styles from leaking in.  Preventing global styles from affecting certain parts of an app is not a problem specific to Vue.  You could manually unset specific global styles in the component or modify your global styles to not be so "global", i.e. using selectors to target only specific parts of the app.

Comment: You can use [vue custom elements](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) for this purpose I think